# Replace keywords with new link in HTML

Tags: php

I want to replace all keywords with new link. `$keyword` is an array of keyword. `$html` is webpage.
If any keyword is found and it is not inside of `title`, `meta` and other rich html tags such as `strong`, `b`, `h1` etc... Then it should be replaced with `$replace`.

```
 foreach($keywords as $key2 => $keyword)
 {
  $keyword = trim($keyword); 
  $replace = '<a href="'.$row['url'].'" title="'.$row['alt'].'" class="linking"'.$nofollow.'>'.$keyword.'</a>';
  $html = preg_replace("/".$keyword."(?!([^<]+)?>)/".$case_insensitive, $replace, $html, $times);
 }
```

This code applying link. but not checking tags correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags